# Why are the elements in the 2nd div, not floating left?

Tags: html, css

**Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/solzy**

I must be brain dead, not sure why the elements in the 2nd div aren't floating correctly. The image should be to the right and copy to the left in the 2nd `copy_block` div.

[image]

HTML

```
    <div class="copy_block">
        <div class="float_left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="How does Who@ help?"/>
        </div>
        <div class="float_right">
            <h2>Header Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi feugiat iaculis odio ut tincidunt. Suspendisse placerat gravida nisi sit amet imperdiet. Duis eget est elit. Cras vitae dignissim lectus, nec pulvinar tellus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque at eros at est blandit mollis ac vulputate eros. Nunc mauris libero, tempor nec aliquam id, tincidunt eget nibh. Maecenas pulvinar sem ac turpis porttitor, nec scelerisque odio egestas. Vestibulum lacus ligula, semper id quam viverra, ultricies congue dui. Curabitur at rhoncus nibh. Aenean luctus justo ac massa ultricies, sit amet pulvinar ipsum fringilla.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="copy_block">
        <div class="float_left">
            <h2>Header Title 2</h2>
            <p>Curabitur arcu neque, tempus eget dolor vel, hendrerit ornare lectus. Donec commodo ante sit amet erat fringilla commodo a in mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec orci odio, pulvinar eu luctus ut, cursus ultrices massa. Maecenas tempor tincidunt hendrerit. Vivamus faucibus scelerisque urna, rutrum hendrerit nisl adipiscing a. Proin ante nisl, vulputate malesuada pharetra id, scelerisque sed ligula.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="float_right">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150 " alt="Why is Who@ different?"/>
        </div>
    <div>

<div>
```

CSS

```
#about-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #686662;
}

.copy_block {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: cyan;
}

.float_left {
   float: left;
}
.float_right {

}
```

Comment: Maybe it is, and your `p` styling has some serious left padding somewhere else in your style sheet. http://jsfiddle.net/F2MJV/

Comment: Did you intend to have a float: right style in this class: .float_right?

Comment: Well, `float_right` doesn't have any styles. And a floating div doesn't get narrower than an ordinary div if you don't restrict its width explicitly. So this one is 100% wide, just like an ordinary div would be.

Comment: Hmm I removed the margins and padding, but still the image isn't floating up http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/solzy

Comment: float_right was just there in case I needed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me with a clear div.

Just write after your first Picture

```
        <div class="copy_block">
            <div class="float_left">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="How does Who@ help?"/>
            </div>
     <div style="clear:left"></div>
```

Comment: @Leon You should stop relaying on clearing floats. Just use `overflow: auto;` on the outter `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a specific width to the floated element. Since you're not floating the `<img />` element directly, the `<div />` that you are floating will be getting its width intrinsically from its children elements (namely the `<p />` tag).

Here is an updated Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bxcha

Comment: Ah thanks! yeah I forgot I needed widths on the divider divs, just brain dead `.div_short {
   width: 30%;
  }
  .div_wide {
   width: 70%;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Floated elements do not “float up” – if you want the image to be on the right and the text content to float *around* it, then you have to put it *before* the text content in your code … and of course actually give it `float:left`, which you did not do.

Your codepen, fixed: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjvIx

(Also removed class `float_right` from first text container and `float_left` from second, because those don’t make sense either, and will make for a totally different effect if floated as well.)

Answer (score 1):

CBroe is correct - placement of your  tag within your HTML is key. I took the liberty of cleaning up your HTML slightly and pushing it into this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andRyanMiller/ZTcRD/). Note that I don't float the text - only the  needs to be floated:

```
img.right {
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    float:right
}

img.left {
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
    float:left
}
```

Comment: Thanks I like your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto;` to your outter `div`s, and you dont need to worry about clearing floats. In this case, `.copy_block`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PmDcX/)**

Edit: You could always do `* { overflow: auto; }` to make sure you dont need to clear any floats, though.